# Database Error When trying to Join Table Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

So i want to fetch data from two tables.
But i got this error :

[image]

Here is my **Query from Model:**

```
public function tampil_edit($id) {
            $this->db->join('tb_m_user', 'tb_m_user.id=tb_m_notaris.id');
            $this->db->select('tb_m_notaris.*,tb_m_user.email as email_notaris');
            return $this->db->get_where('tb_m_notaris', $id);
        }
```

Here is my **Controller :**

```
public function tampiledit($id) {
            $id = ['id' => $id];
            $title['title'] = 'Notaris | Edit';
            $data['notaris']    = $this->m_notaris->tampil_edit($id)->result();

            $this->load->view('template/headercss',$title);
            $this->load->view('template/sidebar');
            $this->load->view('template/navbar');
            $this->load->view('master_data/notaris/edit', $data);
            $this->load->view('template/footerjs');
        }
```

Here Is what the $id contain:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your SQL

```
WHERE id = 45
      ^^
```

This `id` belongs to which table? I notice there are multiple table (`tb_m_notaris`,`tb_m_user`) with `id` column.

**To call function**

```
tampil_edit(45) {} # makesure $id is not an array
```

**In model**

```
public function tampil_edit($id) {
    $this->db->select('tb_m_notaris.*,tb_m_user.email as email_notaris');
    $this->db->from('tb_m_notaris');
    $this->db->join('tb_m_user', 'tb_m_user.id = tb_m_notaris.id');
    $this->db->where('tb_m_notaris.id', $id);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Comment: the id belongs to both of it.

Comment: your query got another error : Message: Array to string conversion

Comment: @HaikalMulyaPutra without `$id = ['id' => $id];` this just pass `$id`

Comment: it gets error on my controller : Call to a member function result() on array

Answer (score 1):

you should pass like this in your controller

```
public function tampiledit($id) {
        $id = ['tb_m_notaris.id' => $id];
        $title['title'] = 'Notaris | Edit';
        $data['notaris']    = $this->m_notaris->tampil_edit($id);

        $this->load->view('template/headercss',$title);
        $this->load->view('template/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('template/navbar');
        $this->load->view('master_data/notaris/edit', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footerjs');
    }
```

Comment: Where do i put it? above the $this->db->join?

Comment: in your controller you can try like this why are you down my answer ??

Comment: it got this error : Message: Array to string conversion. And im not the one that down your answer

Comment: hey, it doesn't show any error but it also doesnt show anything on my screen

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You should try this.

```
public function tampil_edit($id) {
   $this->db->select('tb_m_notaris.*,tb_m_user.email as email_notaris');
   $this->db->join('tb_m_user', 'tb_m_user.id=tb_m_notaris.id');
   $this->db->get_where('tb_m_notaris', array('tb_m_notaris.id' => $id));
   return $this->db->get()->row_array();
}
```

update this in your controller

```
 $data['notaris']    = $this->m_notaris->tampil_edit($id);
```

Comment: it get this error : Message: Array to string conversion

Comment: can you please post screen shot? or what is the $id contains?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function tampil_edit($id) {
   $this->db->select('tb_m_notaris.*,tb_m_user.email as email_notaris');
   $this->db->from('tb_m_notaris');
   $this->db->join('tb_m_user', 'tb_m_user.id=tb_m_notaris.id');
   $this->db->where('tb_m_notaris.id', $id);

   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result_array();
}
```

You need to update your query to this.
As id column exists in both the tables, you need to explicitly provide which table id you want to connect to by mentioning the table name.

Comment: it got another error : Message: Array to string conversion

Comment: Updated the query. Check now